# vue side menu drawer attempt in nuxt.. what is the next step?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

So far I can emit the toggle event on the console I swill share beneath, but I don't know what to do next how do I make my event make a division show I could only make it show by using the v-if="toggle=true"  but that doesn't make it go away just stays there if a create that div.

```
<template>
  <div
    class="drawer-toggle"
    role="button"
    @click="$emit('toggle')">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.drawer-toggle {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 50%;
  width: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .drawer-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
}

.drawer-toggle .bar {
  width: 90%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: white;
}
</style>
```

here is console :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent has to listen for the child emit.  So, in `<TheHeader>`:

```html
<TheSideNavToggle @toggle="doSomething">
```

```js
methods: {
   doSomething() {
      this.showFlag = !this.showFlag
   }
}
```

`@toggle` is listening for an event with the same name as the one emitted, and calling the `doSomething` method.  Had you emitted a value, it would be available as the method argument.

On the item you want to toggle:

```html
<div v-if="showFlag">  <!-- or v-show -->
```